# BadPaddingException when trying to decrypt a text in Base64 encrypted in AES in ECB

Tags: java, encryption, aes

i'm trying to do the 7° challeng of cryptopals and i have to decrypt a file Base64 that was encrypted with the AES in ECB mode. So, i found this code that work with the tutoria stirngs, but when i try with the given data in exercise it give me back the error:

> Error while decrypting: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final
> block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used
> during decryption.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> this is the code:

```
public class ES7 {
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        String file = readBase64("C:\\Users\\Huawei\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Lavoro\\Esercizi\\src\\ES7.txt");
        String res = decrypt(file,"YELLOW SUBMARINE"); --> this gave error of key

        // final String secretKey = "ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!";
        // String encryptedString= "Tg2Nn7wUZOQ6Xc+1lenkZTQ9ZDf9a2/RBRiqJBCIX6o=";
        // String decryptedString = decrypt(encryptedString, secretKey) ; --> this work
    }


    public static void setKey(final String myKey) {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(final String strToDecrypt, final String secret) {
        try {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    private static String readBase64(String file) {
        String filetext = "";
        String line;
        try
        {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                filetext += line;
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filetext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Who told you to use the SHA-1 hash of the key as the key? `YELLOW SUBMARINE` is the key; you don't need to mess with it. Perhaps this was based on some mistaken idea that hashing a password makes it into a more secure key. It doesn't.

Comment: So, i don't need the `setKey` function? can i pass `YELLOW SUBMARINE` directly?

Comment: `SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec("YELLOW SUBMARINE".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII), "AES");`

Comment: OK, that was the solution.Thanks.

Comment: @erickson wouldn't that crash if "YELLOW SUBMARINE" wouldn't be exactly 16 bytes and therefore the exact required key length for AES-128? I've seen sha(-?) used for that purpose quite often (though proper key derivation function might be better, user made up strings have little randomness)

Comment: @zapl `YELLOW SUBMARINE` is a constant and has sixteen bytes. The cipher text was encrypted with that key and won't decrypt with a different key. If you are speaking generally, a proper key derivation function **will be better,** and one round of SHA-1 is inadequate for anything worth encrypting.